# Rotation on touch with gyroscope in a mobile device behaving in a weird manner

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, touch, gyroscope

I have been using the gvr sdk in my project to get a 360 view during the video playback through the camera. But when I rotate the camera on touch, the rotation itself is behaving in a weird manner i.e. during the landscape mode, rotation in y-axis is working fine but when the gyroscope is moved towards the right or left, the x-axis rotation is behaving as z-axis rotation. Please help. Below is the code for simple rotation in x and y axis using a touch input on the device.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RCPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static RCPlayer Instance;
    //public GameObject Head;
    //public GameObject Camera;

    Vector3 FirstPoint;
    Vector3 SecondPoint;
    float xAngle;
    float yAngle;
    float xAngleTemp;
    float yAngleTemp;

    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        xAngle = 0;
        yAngle = 0;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yAngle, xAngle, 0);
    }

    void Update()
    {      
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                FirstPoint = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                xAngleTemp = xAngle;
                yAngleTemp = yAngle;
            }

            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            {
                SecondPoint = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

                if (FirstPoint - SecondPoint == Vector3.zero)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    xAngle = xAngleTemp + (SecondPoint.x - FirstPoint.x) * 180 / Screen.width;
                    yAngle = yAngleTemp - (SecondPoint.y - FirstPoint.y) * 180 / Screen.height;
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-yAngle * 0.5f, -xAngle * 0.5f, 0.0f);
                }
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: what gyroscope gets moved? do you mean the gearVR controller?

Comment: Even if I move the gyroscope with the phone's gyroscope input or if I move the gyroscope by using the gvrHead script, this problem still occurs. I'm not using the gearVR Controller. I am using a regular mobile phone.

Comment: gyroscope tracks rotation, not movement, I am unsure what you mean

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. Let me start again:
 - My scene loads with the camera pointing to the center of scene (Pos #1)
 - I move the phone to the right and the camera moves to the right due to gyro movement 
 - Now if I use touch to move the camera back to position #1, the camera rotates on the z-axis instead of x-axis. 
- Ideally the touch movement on x-axis should rotate the camera on the x-axis and the touch movement on y-axis should rotate the camera on the y-axis.

I expect the gyro movement and touch based movement to work the same way, but that doesn't happen.

Comment: first of all, with gyro the action you make is rotation, not movement. the error sounds like using Vector3(x,z) which translates to Vector3(x,z,0), not Vector3(x,0,z) - I make this mistake quite often. post some code if you need more help

Comment: @zambari I have updated my question with the code for simple touch rotation on the mobile device. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I have tried your code and it seems it performs the rotation perfectly (nothing wrong with it on paper too), I can't seem to see your problem. you can always parent the tracked camera to an empty object with the rotation script

Comment: The main camera is the child of a head gameobject and the head gameobject is the child of the GVR main gameobject. The script is attached to the GVR main gameobject. If I attach the script to the main camera then the rotation stops working. I am using the gvr sdk for vr implementations in our product. I will also upload a gif or a video to help you understand the problem better but thank you very much for the help. Thank you.

Comment: @zambari Sorry for the very late response but I got the solution for the problem some time ago. The issue was that while moving in the x axis the head rotation for the VR was required an offset in order to interpolate between the two values. Thank you.